# Cluster Monte Carlo algorithms for $n$-body interactions

Tags: statistical-mechanics, computational-physics, critical-phenomena

Suppose I wanted to perform a Monte-Carlo numerical simulation of an Ising-like model, with a Hamiltonian of the form
$$
-\beta H = J \sum_{\langle i j \rangle} \sigma_i \sigma_j + g \sum_{ijk\ell \in\square} \sigma_i \sigma_j \sigma_k \sigma_{\ell}
$$
where the latter sum is over square plaquettes. (The particular model isn't so crucial; I'm just writing down the simplest model which illustrates the question.)

Of course, one could always employ the Metropolis or other single-flip algorithms to study such a model. However, if $g = 0$, then there are very nice cluster algorithms such as the Wolff algorithm which can dramatically reduce critical slowing-down near the critical point.

My question is: do there exist similar cluster algorithms for $g \neq 0$? Or more generally, can one construct cluster algorithms for models beyond two-body interacting models? I have tried looking online for such an algorithm, but in my limited search I have not found anything. Any references would be greatly appreciated!